# some error in for loop to fetch data from excel in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testng, extentreports

```
@Test
    public void passTest() throws IOException {
        File src = new File("F:\\drive f\\DemoReport.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        int rowcount = sheet1.getLastRowNum();
        for(int i=1;i<=rowcount;i++) {

            String str = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
            String str1 = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
            double j = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(3).getNumericCellValue();
            fis.close();

            String exp1 = "Found";
            String exp2 = "Not Found";
            if(str.equals(exp1)) {
                logger=extent.createTest(str1);
                Assert.assertTrue(true);
                logger.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel(str1 + " found at index " + j, ExtentColor.GREEN));
            }
            else if(str.equals(exp2)) {
                logger=extent.createTest(str1);
                Assert.assertTrue(true);
                logger.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(str1 + "is not found", ExtentColor.RED));
            }
        }
    }
```

i am using testNG to generate extent report, i have some data in my excel file so i fetch them from excel now if the string fetched from excel is "Found" then my test should pass otherwise fail, but in this code it only fetches the data from the first row in the excel.

Comment: I think it's because you call `fis.close();` inside loop

Comment: Take a few minutes to learn how to add breakpoints and debug this script in your IDE. It would have helped you find this problem almost immediately.

Comment: thanks for suggestions, there is a null pointer exception, now its working

Answer (score 0):

You are closing theFileInputStream inside the for-loop. Use **fis.close();** after for-loop ends.